# Google search based on country

Tags: search-engine, google-search

I am using Google Chrome and Google search engine as default. My current location is **India**. When i search anything, it gives me result from **India**. That's great.

Now, I want to have **searched** **result** from another country e.g. **UAE**. Where should i make the change to get the result from UAE or any other country.

Comment: change the url from `.in` to https://www.google.ae/?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl

Comment: but it is also showing results from India. And what about other countries also. Does Google support different url for each country ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good artile here:
http://www.entrepreneurs-journey.com/322/how-to-search-google-as-a-local-in-any-country/

You can change the query parameter 'gl' value to your desired country to get the result by that country. for example ...

This will show you the results from japan

https://www.google.com/search?q=kangaroo&gws_rd=ssl&gl=jp

and This will show you the results from us

https://www.google.com/search?q=kangaroo&gws_rd=ssl&gl=us

Hope it clears.